# NHibernate one-to-many fetching only single row

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using nhibernate with c# and I have two class `PartnerOrgUnit` and `PartnerUser`
and in database I have 3 `PartnerUsers` which is associated with `PartnerOrgUnit`.

But When I do `_partnerOrgUnitRepository.FindAll()` it will just give me only first `PartnerUsers` row.

FindAll() method includes -

```
session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>()
```

My code is as follows -

```
public class PartnerOrgUnit {
    public IList<PartnerUsers> PartnerUsers { get; set; }
}

public class PartnerUsers{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
}
```

In `PartnerOrgUnit.hbm.xml` file I have code like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="PMPS.Model.Partner.OrgUnit"
    assembly="PMPS.Model">

        <bag name="PartnerUsers" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="PartnerUserId"/>
            <one-to-many class="PMPS.Model.Partner.User.PartnerUsers"/>
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: you should post your `FindAll()` method

Comment: If you enable NHibernate logging, what are the SQL statements issued? Are they giving the expected result from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inverse="true"` says `PartnerUsers` should maintain the association but it has no backreference to do so. I suspect that there is code which just adds the 3 `PartnerUsers` to the `PartnerOrgUnit` but Nhibernate will not save them.